# Message is added to queue, wait to get your coupons soon

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I'm trying to create auto generate coupons in magento 2 but its showing as below:

> Message is added to queue, wait to get your coupons soon

Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: can you set up cron? it will process using cron job

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try to manually process queue with this command

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:list
```

view a list of all consumers

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start <queue_name>
```

pass queue_name for process the queue

Comment: Thanks. Working now

Comment: @Siva do you know what is the queue name for coupon ?

Comment: @sumeetbajaj, try running this command, php bin/magento queue:consumers:start codegeneratorProcessor

Comment: @Siva when running these commands, but the output is not coming on command prompt

Comment: check whether the coupon got generated or not

Comment: yes coupon code is generated but whenever I have to generate coupon codes then I have to run this command

Comment: hi @sumeetbajaj when display this "Message is added to queue, wait to get your coupons soon". it means it will be generate coupon code base on cron running, if you are not waiting for it and just create coupon code than run above command.

Answer (score 6):

Try running the following commands:

```
bin/magento cron:run
bin/magento queue:consumers:start codegeneratorProcessor
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `bin/magento queue:consumers:list` you should see this:

```
product_action_attribute.update
product_action_attribute.website.update
exportProcessor
codegeneratorProcessor
async.operations.all
```

After run `bin/magento queue:consumers:start codegeneratorProcessor`. Wait a couple of seconds and refresh the page to see the newly generated coupons.